# How to change button's look upon and after clicking?

Tags: css

When I press on the button, I want its look to change. But immediately after pressing, I want it to return to the original look before it was being clicked--like a real-life button.

Here's my CSS:

```
.choice {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    width: 15.5em;
    padding: 1.2em 3em;
    margin: 0.3em 0em;
    border: 0.3em solid grey;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
  }
  .choice:hover {
    border: 0.5em solid rgb(165, 42, 42);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .choice:active {
    border: 0.5em solid rgb(165, 42, 42);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .choice:visited {
    border: 0.3em solid grey;
    border-radius: 0.3em;
  }
```

How will I achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Did you try `:focus` ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to change or remove the rule with the `:hover` pseudoclass so that you can see the effect of the rule with the `:active` pseudoclass...

Comment: Yes, I tried :focus but it didn't work. But when I tried removing the :hover and left the :active, it worked! My problem right now, though, is that whenever I click on my buttons, there is this blue something. How can I remove it?

Comment: I guess you mean the [focus ring](https://medium.com/hackernoon/removing-that-ugly-focus-ring-and-keeping-it-too-6c8727fefcd2)?

Comment: No, that's not it. I don't know what it's called but I'm sure it's not the blue border box that's just around the button. I was referring to the blue box that really covers the whole button upon clicking, making the changes I had on my .choice:active not that visible.

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian Is it possible that some of your other css is overwriting the styles given here? Could you check in the browser to see to which css tag these colors that you see refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could resolve this issue by adding

.choice:active

That event would trigger on click and after that it would return to the default styles.

If you set "focus" state it would be activated if you switch to button with "tab" and stay active after you click the button until you click somewhere else on the page(i.e. to lose focus on it).

```css
  button { font-weight: normal; color: black; }
  button:active { font-weight: bold; color:blue; }
```

```html
<button>
  When clicked, my text turns blue AND bold!<br />
  But after that my text just turns black
</button>
```

Comment: @BartHofland yes, but he used active and focus with the same styling, which changed the result. I suggest he use only active without focus.

Comment: Ah yes. I guess that would be correct. Luckily, the OP is not using `:focus` just yet. But I also assume the OP also needs to change or remove the `:hover` as well, because that might interfere with `:active` as well. (I assume you meant `:hover` instead of `:focus` in your previous comment. ;))

Comment: @BartHofland yes, you are correct. I'm not sure why I took hover for focus - that's my bad.

Comment: @MitkoDelibaltov how do I change the color and size of my button's border?

Comment: @ZeddrixFabian you can change them with border-width: 10px;  border-color: red; (change values to your desired ones). You can find more border values here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp